# AutoMapper : How to ignore child of child object from mapping using AutoMapper in c#

Tags: c#, automapper

I have below class structure

```
    public class Parent
    {
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        public string ParentName { get; set; }
        public Child Child { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentMap
    {
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        public string ParentName { get; set; }
        public Child Child { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public int ChildID { get; set; }
        public string ChildName { get; set; }
        public InnerChild InnerChild { get; set; }
    }

    public class InnerChild
    {
        public int InnerChildID { get; set; }
        public string InnerChildName { get; set; }
        public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to map `Parent` class with `ParentMap` class. After mapping, I need `Parent`'s `Child` object. But I don't need `Parent`'s `Child.InnerChild` object(Its ok to set it to `null`).
I've already tried with `ForPath()` as below. But it will stop mapping entire `Child` object.

```
CreateMap<Parent, ParentMap>()
  .ForPath(o => o.Child.InnerChild, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Can some one tell me how do I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one quick way to resolve your issue

```
CreateMap<Parent, ParentMap>()
    .AfterMap((src, dst) =>
    {
        dst.Child.InnerChild = null;
    });
```